# Sed/grep only the last section of numbers (see example)

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I would like to get from this list with grep/sed:

```
some-text_of-1.6.6-11
text_r6.5.5-text1.6.6-11
text_r6.5.5-something6.6.6-11
text_r6.5.5-yess-2.6.6-11
```

Only the last numbers, so:

```
1.6.6-11
6.6.6-11
2.6.6-11
```

There could be anything(any character) before 1.6.6-11, 2.6.6-11, 6.6.6-11, but nothing after.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: is it always of form number.number.number-number?

Comment: There could be numbers before the last section of numbers, but not always.

Comment: If these are e.g. Debian package version numbers, the full spec is a lot more complex than the simple samples you provide.

Answer (score 1):

Use sed and sort.

```
$ sed 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\)$/\1/g' file | sort -u
1.6.6-11
2.6.6-11
6.6.6-11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o [0-9][0-9.-]*$ file
```

**Explanation:**

```
[0-9]    # Match a digit
[0-9.-]* # Match digits, dots or dashes
$        # Anchor the search to the end of the string
```

The `-o` option tells `grep` to only output the matching part of the line instead of the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'H;s/.*//;x
:cycle
   s/\(.*\)\([-0-9.]\{1,\}\)$/\2\1/
   t cycle
s/\n.*//;s/^[-.]*//' YourFile
```

more generic to any length of number and dot, minus

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be grep or egrep, limiting the output to the match with -o:

```
egrep -o "[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]-[0-9]+" inputfile
```

Or with sed:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\-[0-9]\+\)$/\1/' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk -F"[-.a-z]" '{print $(NF-3)"."$(NF-2)"."$(NF-1)"-"$NF}' file
1.6.6-11
1.6.6-11
6.6.6-11
2.6.6-11
```

By setting Field Separator to `-`, `.` or `a-z` we get the last `4` fields.